# I need a C++ interface to S4s server

Tags: c++, data-storage

[Does anyone have a C++ Object interface for the S4 server?](http://www.supersimplestorageservice.com/#api)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

using [gSoap](http://www.cs.fsu.edu/~engelen/soap.html), you can generate header and support code from the provided [wsdl](http://www.supersimplestorageservice.com/API/S4.asmx?wsdl)
see this [how-to](http://www.cs.fsu.edu/~engelen/soapmain.html#howto) for some sample code.

But **what the point of the service, it's like copying to /dev/null in my opinion**